# What does "society's finest" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this particular sentence...

> Well, it was either leave her outside at the mercy of society's finest or bring her unconscious body in here

who are the "society's finest"? Does it refer to police or to good samaritans, or to something else?

Comment: Welcome to English Langauge & Usage. Your question is a little unclear due to lack of context. If you need assistance in framing a question, please visit our Help Page ["How to ask a question"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ***finest***: police officers —usually used with the possessive form of a city or area -- _the city's finest_

Answer (score 4):

Based on no context, this is just a guess but I would imagine it's most likely being said sardonically.

It's not referring to police or good samaritans, but instead to criminals, miscreants and/or other ne'er-do-wells who would likely prey on an unconscious, unprotected woman left outside alone.

Answer (score 3):

I understand "society's finest" in this sentence sarcastically, as @freeling10 pointed out, it's about the exact opposite of whom you would refer as society's finest.